# How to sort an OrderedDictionary using Linq in C# (using .NET 3.5)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to sort an OrderedDictionary (System.Collections.Specialized)
I have this code:

```
var od = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary();
od.Add("a1", 3);
od.Add("a2", 5);
od.Add("a3", 2);
od.Add("a4", 4);
```

I wish to sort it using values. Can I do it using Linq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following will give you a sorted dictionary based on your OrderedDictionary.

```
var normalOrderedDictionary= od.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                       .OrderBy(r=> r.Value)
                       .ToDictionary(c=> c.Key, d=> d.Value);
```

There is one thing though, `ToDictionary` returned a regular dictionary but the order is maintained in the dictionary for the lookup, as soon as any new item is inserted in the dictionary, they the order cannot be guaranteed. To avoid this, use `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` which has a constructor that takes a regular dictionary as parameter

```
var sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(normalOrderedDictionary);
```

*(Make sure to replace `string` with the correct types for Key and value in the above line)*.

Output:

```
foreach (var entry in sortedDictionary)
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);

Key: a3 Value: 2
Key: a1 Value: 3
Key: a4 Value: 4
Key: a2 Value: 5
```

Comment: Thanks Habib..your answer also worked. I just dont have too many reputation points.

Comment: It does ROCKS! :D Tried to come up with this yesterday but didn't get it at first. Now looking at this sample everything is clear as a bright sky...

Comment: Will `ToDictionary()` craft a generic (non-ordered) dictionary?

Comment: Yes - this answer is wrong. `ToDictionary()` returns a regular `Dictionary<>` where the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @NetMage, you are right, `ToDictionary` will return a regular dictionary, although its order is guaranteed to be maintained for look ups *(because of the OrderBy at the time of creation)*, but as soon as a new item is added , the order can't be guaranteed. I have modified the answer to reflect that. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, the order is specifically not guaranteed for lookup. The current implementation happens to preserve order, but future implementations may not: "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined." From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: @NetMage, yes, the above is correct, but if the dictionary is created with `OrderBy`  or based on a sorted set, then as long as the dictionary is not modified it will return the ordered results. That is because the inner implementation is based on array and hashtable. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582682/building-a-sorted-dictionary-using-todictionary)

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate over the values/entries by the value easily.  You'll just have to cast to the appropriate type in order to activate the linq features.

```
var sortedOrder = od.Values
    .Cast<int>()        // this is an enumeration of ints
    .OrderBy(i => i);;  // enumerate through ordered by the value

foreach (var item in sortedOrder)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Great..This is going to help. Also what does the AsQueryable() method do. Can I linq query for sorting.

Comment: `AsQueryable()` simply casts the collection as an `IQueryable<T>` (as opposed to `IEnumerable<T>`). IQueryables accept [LINQ expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx) as well as lambda expressions when creating queries making it easier to create dynamic queries.