# Building a sorted dictionary using ToDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I'm not an expert in C# and LINQ.

I have a `Dictionary`, which I understand a hash table, that is, keys are not sorted.

```
dataBase = new Dictionary<string, Record>()
```

`Record` is a user-defined class that holds a number of data for a given key string.

I found an interesting example that converts this `Dictionary` into a *sorted* dictionary by LINQ:

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in dataBase orderby entry.Key ascending select entry)
.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

This code works correctly. The resulting `sortedDict` is sorted by keys.

**Question**: I found that `sortedDict` is still a hash table, a type of:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Record>
```

I expected the resulting dictionary should be a sort of `map` as in C++ STL, which is generally implemented as a (balanced) binary tree to maintain the ordering of the keys. However, the resulting dictionary is still a hash table.

How `sortedDict` can maintain the ordering? A hash table can't hold the ordering of the keys. Is the implementation of C#'s `Generic.Dictionary` other than a typical hash table?

Comment: By using `ToDictionary()`, you asked for and got a `Dictionary`. If you want to maintain a sorted Diecionary, use `SortedDictionary`

Comment: I know. But, I need a sorted dictionary at the last moment. My question is that how `Dictionary` can maintain the ordering, which is odd to me. The LINQ code actually builds a *sorted* dictionary, while the type is still a dictionary.

Comment: The linq just sorts the `Dictionary` it does not create a `SortedDictionary`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Dictionary` maintains two data structures: a flat array that's kept in insertion order for enumeration, and the hash table for retrieval by key.

If you use `ToDictionary()` on a sorted set, it will be in order when enumerated, but it won't be maintained in order.  Any newly inserted items will be added to the back when enumerating.

Edit: If you want to rely on this behaviour, I would recommend looking at the MSDN docs to see if this is guaranteed, or just incidental.

Answer (score 10):

`SortedDictionary` takes an existing `Dictionary` in the constructor so making a `SortedDictionary` is very easy.

But you can make it an extension method if you want then you can use `dataBase.ToSortedDictionary()`

```
public static SortedDictionary<K, V> ToSortedDictionary<K,V>(this Dictionary<K, V> existing)
{
    return new SortedDictionary<K, V>(existing);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the linq code looks building a sorted dictionary, but the sorting is done by the linq, not the dictionary itself, whereas a SortedDictionary should maintain the sorting by itself.

to get a sorted dictionary, use `new SortedDictionary<string, Record>(yourNormalDictionary);`

if you want to make it more accessible, then you may write an extension to the ienumerable:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static SortedDictionary<T1, T2> ToSortedDictionary<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T2> source, Func<T2, T1> keySelector)
    {
        return new SortedDictionary<T1, T2>(source.ToDictionary(keySelector));
    }
}
```