# Is there ToSortedDictionary in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am refactoring a code like this:

```
var result = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

foreach (var item in foo)
{
    result[item.id] = item.name;
}
foreach (var item in bar)
{
    result[item.id] = item.name;
}
return result;
```

I would like to write:

```
return foo.Concat(bar).ToSortedDictionary(i => i.id, i => i.name);
```

but I did not find it in Linq?

Comment: `foo.Concat(bar).Aggregate(new SortedDictionary<int, string>(), (d, i) => { d[i.id] = i.name; return d; })`

Answer (score 2):

First solution is to prepare `Dictionary`and use as an argument to create a `SortedDictionary`:

```
return new SortedDictionary<T1, T2>(foo.Concat(bar).ToDictionary())
```

Another option is to write an extension method like this:

```
public static SortedDictionary<K, V> ToSortedDictionary<K,V>(this Dictionary<K, V> existing)
{
    return new SortedDictionary<K, V>(existing);
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster , your example is great and in that case it is no possible to have a sorted whatever. But author of the question want to join two collections and sort the result, I believe he's expect two collection with different ids, so that the result would be possible to sort.

Comment: Yeah, I was confusing SortedDictionary with OrderedDictionary. Anyway, see duplicate.

Comment: @Alex the OrderBy isn't necessary - and actually wont' do anything in the end as the SortedDictionary will have its own comparer

Comment: @simonalexander2005, good to know, thanks. I'll edit answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return new SortedDictionary<T1, T2>(foo.Concat(bar).ToDictionary())`; or you can write your own extension method.

As to why it doesn't exist, there's plenty of similar methods that don't exist- the basics are provided and whatever else you need you can easily make yourself.

Comment: `foo.Concat(bar).ToDictionary()` does not maintain order.

Comment: @CodeCaster no, but you can provide an IComparer to the `SortedDictionary` constructor; or let it use the default sort order if that's what you want

Comment: I've just looked in the linked question, and I don't think my answer is any different to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582737/318414

Comment: You know, I might have just once again misunderstood the question as well as your answer, retracted my vote.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks :) to clarify for anyone else looking, the original code using the `foreach` loops won't maintain insertion order either - a sorted dictionary will use a comparer to sort the contents of the dictionary regardless of insertion order.

Comment: What is the overhead of this?

Comment: @Boiethios the overhead compared to what?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 To my solution obviously

Comment: compared to the original code, you mean? It's easy enough to write a couple of tests to do some benchmarking