# C# Sorting ordered dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, collections, ordereddictionary

I am working with ordered dictionary (as it is the data structure that gives me functionality to access items by both key and index.)

I am trying to sort it using bubble sort ,

(specially because some legacy code that will be calling this has comparator defined with only one method, How one element is less than the other element.
ILzObjectComparator_Less(ByVal First As Object, _
                                          ByVal Second As Object) As Boolean )
)

While my code kind of works, i.e. it is sorting by value, it is changing key-value mappings.

Here is my method -

```
    public void SortUsingComparer(LzCollections.ILzObjectComparator Comparator)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < od.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < od.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if(Comparator.Less( od[i+1],od[i]))
                {
                    temp = od[i + 1];
                    od[i + 1] = od[i];
                    od[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There is one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833905/how-to-sort-an-ordereddictionary-using-linq-in-c-sharp-using-net-3-5) , but that used OrderBy which I am not able to map with ILzObjectComparator that our legacy code uses.)
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using .NET's built-in support for sorting using your own [comparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Which ordered dictionary class are you using? And what is `od`? Can you show your data structures?

Answer (score -1):

You are referencing not the `Elements` in the `Dictionary`but their `Values`: `od[i]`

You could try to use the `Elements` instead: `od.ElementAt(i)` but this won't allow you assign anything to it nor can you do an `InsertAt()`.

Note, that I'm not even sure that the order in a `Dictionary` is guaranteed.

So, I don't think you can do that.

But, of course, there is the [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

But since you need to use a custom comparer, I guess you have to switch to another collection class, maybe `List<Tuple<>>`?

Here is an example

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> od = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
```

After adding a few elements you can sort it, by by either Item:

```
for (int j = 0; j < od.Count; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < od.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // insert your custom comparer here:
        if (od.ElementAt(i + 1).Item1 < od.ElementAt(i).Item1)
        {
            var temp0 = od.ElementAt(i);
            var temp1 = od.ElementAt(i + 1);
            od.RemoveAt(i);
            od.RemoveAt(i);
            od.Insert(i, temp1);
            od.Insert(i+1, temp0);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course a `Tuple` is less helpful than a `Dictionary`, uniqueness for example etc..

Comment: THis is not useful, because when you are using a dictionary you can do a key lookup and have unique entries, with list this becomes inefficient.

Comment: What has a key-lookup do with sorting/comparing? - OTOH I don't think the question itself makes a lot of sense. He should use a cusotm comparer when creating the OrderedDixtionary. No idea what he want to achieve with a bubble sort..