# How to remove element from Dictionary that uses Tuple

Tags: c#, dictionary, element

I am using C# 4.5 on my winform.  I have a Dictionary with a Tuple named ParamList that uses this:

```
new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>();
```

I am able to iterate through ParamList to place the elements in my ComboBox.  What I want to be able to do is move the elements up or down with a button click event or remove an element altogether with a different button click. I cannot figure out how to do so.  Thanks.

Comment: A `Tuple` as `key`???? +_+

Comment: You can't "move" elements within a dictionary - it's not ordered. Removing an element is easy - but ordering isn't.

Comment: @kevintjuh93@ Yes, why not? That's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I would never recommend that lol

Comment: you are saying ParamList but you have dictionary (?)

Comment: @kevintjuh93 click on jon skeet account, see his reputation. rethink about what you have said!

Comment: @kevintjuh93 It's a perfectly fine concept.  There's no problem at all with doing that.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx), see also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13833905/1997232) question.

Comment: @Sinatr How can you move the item inside `OrderedDictionary`? Sounds like a plain `List` to me.

Comment: @IvanStoev, it has [`Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.insert.aspx) method (same as `List`). You delete item and insert it at needed position. But as `Dictionary` you still have all benefits of keyed collection, though non-generic dictionary.

Comment: @Sinatr Oops, you are right! I was thinking for `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. MS with their namings :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Tuple to remove

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>();
dict.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b"), "c");
dict.Remove(new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b"));

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(dict.Count == 0);
```

Comment: Note that you should typically be using `Tuple.Create` to create tuples as it allows the generic arguments to be inferred.  This answer also doesn't even mention the fact that he wants to reorder the items.

Comment: Eser, this is working for the remove.  What should I be doing for moving elements on a button click event?

Comment: I just moved items in my ComboBox and that took care of everything.  Thanks